# Bootstrap versus AngularUI

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am looking for a pro/con argument for using either Bootstrap or AngularUI with Angular. From what I understand, AngularUI is a set of directives that have Bootstrap so I can use Bootstrap responsive aspects. Can I also use straight Bootstrap and Angular instead of AngularUI? What are the benefits of either approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hopefully this will help.

Angular UI, but more specifically *UI-Bootstrap* **is** bootstrap written **natively** for AngularJS. The reason being is some features in bootstrap use jQuery, which when used with angular, can produce adverse results than what is expected.

This can become very opinionated. But seriously, use Angular-UI. You'll potentially run into more problems if you try to mix the two (Bootstrap 3 + Angular).

**Quote from** ["Thinking in AngularJS" if I have a jQuery background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)

> Don't even use jQuery. Don't even include it. It will hold you back. And when you come to a problem that you think you know how to solve in jQuery already, before you reach for the $, try to think about how to do it within the confines the AngularJS. If you don't know, ask! 19 times out of 20, the best way to do it doesn't need jQuery and to try to solve it with jQuery results in more work for you.

Please see [Stop using jQuery as a crutch in angular](http://joelhooks.com/blog/2013/07/27/using-angularjs-stop-using-jquery-as-a-crutch/) for a general idea of the issues.

**EDIT:** Changed language

Comment: +1 for someone finally mentioning that Angular UI is bootstrap written in Angular directives.

Answer (score 2):

Although some people are marking this as opinion there is an answer here that can help the OP.

AngularUI and Bootstrap really aren't a either/or type of choice.  They can happily, and probably should live, side by side.

Bootstrap is mainly a CSS library with some javascript UI bits on the side.  The AngularUI library is just more UI bits coded up to work better with angular. There is a lot of overlap between the two but each project is a little different so use each where it makes sense.

I'd assume that your app will benefit from using both.  I have 3-4 apps right now with both libraries included and happily working together.

Comment: Any examples of how AngularUI "works better"

Comment: Fancy UI via directives instead of $(stuff).uithing(), managing scope and the digest cycle for you, no $scope.apply needed.

Answer (score 1):

- [Angular UI](http://angular-ui.github.io/) A lot of helpful utilites for Angular
- [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) CSS Framework
- [UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) Angular UI utilities focused on making Bootstrap work awesome with Angular

;)